# ASP.NET MVC - Backbone js - Organize multi page mvc app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js

We have a project using ASP.NET MVC  4 and it is a multi page mvc web app. We are planning to use Backbone js as the front end javascript framework . What is the best practice or suggestion to  organize the backbone js code for the multi page mvc web app?

How it will be organized if we use Knockout js instead of backbone js.?

Thanks,

Sarathy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Backbone is best used for SPA's (Single page apps). It is designed to help bring structure to javascript heavy applications. You first need to tell us why you are looking to use either of these libraries and a description of the site or app you are building? Are you using MVC 4 Web API, because Backbone connects to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface and Web API is a perfect fit for this.

The only reason I would see to use Backbone for a multi-page mvc web app, is if you are looking for the app to function with javascript disabled and progressively enhance the app with Backbone. If you are looking to use pushstate, then you would also need to serve the individual pages.

I think the best bet is to look at [TODOMVC](http://todomvc.com/) to get a feel of the different libraries. Look how they work and see which, if any, would be a good fit for your app.